# Voice Activation: Send Email: Recipient Name not working

Tags: email, voice-command

I have disabled Contacts sync with all my Google Accounts and deleted all my contacts. Then I added a simple email contact Type: Phone (as opposed to SIM or Google Account). Name Bob, and a valid address for Bob's company email.

I say "Send Email To Bob (pause) Test" And I get an email form with a blank To and a body that says "To Bob Test".

How can I fix this?

It is a bit odd, because it is obviously expecting a pause in the middle of the whole thing, but it still manages to not realize that "Send Email To Bob,,,, Test" means "Send Email To Bob,, and put Test in the body".

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be a Google contact. Your voice request is sent to Google's servers to be parsed and it looks for the information in your Google Contacts. The server can't query your phone.

See this [Google Help thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=027fcc5de41efbfc&hl=en).